# MATLAB - understanding structure of Event location function

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

In my textbook I have encountered an example of a function I am supposed to use when specifying an event location for a system of ODEs.  The function example is as follows:

```
function [value, isterminal, dircn] = proj(t,z,flag);
g = 9.81;
if nargin < 3 | isempty(flag)
    value = [z(2); 0; z(4); -g];
else
    switch flag
        case 'events'
            value = z(3);
            isterminal = 1;
            dircn = -1;
        otherwise
            error('function not programmed for this event');
    end
end
```

There is one part of the logic here which I don't understand.  Say that I activate the "events" option and then run ode45.  How, then, can ode45 actually read the system of equations (which is specified in the above function as `value = [z(2); 0; z(4); -g];`)?  I have ran ode45 based on the above function, after specifying tspan and inital conditions of course, and it works like a charm.  But I don't understand how ode45 can read the system properly when it is only presented in the "if"-part of the script above.

If anyone can explain the logic here, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It depends how you call it. Ode45 works numerically - so it doesn't care how the function looks. But it seems your function is strange - as in case without flag it returns a 4x1 vector but in the case of events an 1x1 vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I can explain some parts. As I wrote above it is strange that the dimension of `value` changes.

given your statespace and the names of your variables it looks like 2 dimensional motion.

in the case of no flag it seems that state space is:

1. horizontal position (x)
2. horizontal speed (vx)
3. vertical position (y)
4. vertical speed (vy)

**correction**
It seems that ode can send `'events'` when you specify them. So your function outputs 3rd component of the state space. Look at this site explaining it: http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/math/f1-662913.html

<strike>unless you specify it beforehand ode can't send `'events'` to the function so this part will not be called.</strike>

But your function won't work anyway - as the derivative would need to have same dimension as the statespace (4x1). But has only 1x1.

But I really don't know what you mean by "specifying an event location". Maybe the secret is hidden there.

With some creativity I think you could use the function to extract the 3rd component of the state space.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  What is confusing me is that I get a 4x1 vector regardless of whether I activate "events" or not.  The only difference is that the calculations terminate when z(3) hits zero if it is activated.  However, since the "else"-statement only specifies a 1x1 vector as output for value, I don't understand why we continue to get a 4x1 vector.  We are supposed to get a 4x1 vector, according to my textbook, but the book only provides the code above, and doesn't bother explaining the internal logic of it. To me, it seems like the output should only be 1x1 when 'events' is activated.

Comment: From what I understand now. The events function gives abort conditions for the integration. So it's result is supposed to be processed differently. The confusing part of the example is that the derivation function and the event function are mangled into one. If you are allowed I think it would make sense to transfer it in the form given in the mathworks example I linked (it's actually the same example in 1d - should be easy to transform).

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I saw another example in another book that made a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the `if` command:

```
if nargin < 3 | isempty(flag)
    value = [z(2); 0; z(4); -g];
else
```

If number of arguments is less than 3 or if variable `flag` is empty, then set variable `value` to `[z(2); 0; z(4); -g]`. Otherwise, if variable `flag` is `'events'`, then set variable `value` to `z(3)`, and when `flag` is not `'events'`, report an error. So this function always assigns some return value for variable `value` or, reports an error using `error` command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I follow your logic, but what I don't get is that when I call upon ode42, musn't ode42 then also read the value = [z(2); 0; z(4); -g] in order for it to compute the system of differential equation in the first place?  If I run ode24 with 'events' activated, I still get a solution set of four vectors - the only difference being that it now terminates when z(3) hits 0.

Answer (score 0):

I can supplement a bit more information about how we proceed after writing the function above.  We then define, say:

```
tspan = [0 6];
z0 = [0, 5*cos(pi/4), 0, 5*sin(pi/4)];
options = odeset('events','on');
[t y] = ode42('proj',tspan,z0,options)
```

By writing this the output is 5 columns, 1 column for `tspan` , and 1 column for each of the z-values (`z(1)`, `z(2)`, `z(3)` and `z(4)`).  When `z(3)` hits zero, the calculations are terminated since the "event" occurs.

If, on the other hand I do not include the `options = odeset('events','on')` line, and simply write:

```
[t y] = ode42('proj',tspan,z0)
```

The calculations are performed for the entire `tspan` range.

Yet, I still fail to see how `ode42` is capable of calculating all the output vectors when we activate "events" since it then looks logical me that MatLab should only execute the "else"-statement in the "proj"-function.  And in this part of the function, the actual system of the differential equations is not included.